# Entradas por página en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Existe alguna forma de añadir entradas a páginas específicas. Es decir, tengo 5 páginas, en la principal que se vean todas las entradas y la página donde están, y en las otras las entradas que le corresponden. Algo así como usar categorías, pero en este caso publicar entradas por página.

Comment: y por qué no te convence usar las categorías, si para ti es trivial poner las categorías adecuadas en cada post?

Comment: Entonces cómo puedo asociar las categorías por página, para que cuando seleccione una página salgan las entradas de la categoría correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es crear custom queries sobre cada pagina:

```
   <?php

   /*
   Template Name: Mi pagina
   */

   get_header();

   $q = array (
       'category_name' => 'lacategoria',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'paged' => $paged,
   );
   query_posts($q);
   if(have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   //Loop
   endwhile; endif;

   get_footer();
   ?>
```

Tendrias que realizar esto con cada pagina individual.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y [bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo en una sola página, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
switch ( $categoria ) {
    case "categoria1":
        $n_entradas = 4;
        break;
    case "categoria2":
        $n_entradas = 5;
        break;
    case "categoria3":
        $n_entradas = 6;
        break;
    case "categoria4":
        $n_entradas = 7;
        break;
    case "categoria5":
        $n_entradas = 8;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        $n_entradas = 10;
        break;
}

// The Args
$args  = array (
    'category_name' => $categoria,
    'posts_per_page' => $n_entradas,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

// The Query
query_posts( $args );
```